# Real FFT output

Tags: signal-processing, dft, kissfft

I have implemented fft into at32ucb series ucontroller using kiss fft library and currently struggling with the output of the fft. 
My intention is to analyse sound coming from piezo speaker. 
Currently, the frequency of the sounder is 420Hz which I successfully got from the fft output (cross checked with an oscilloscope). However, the output frequency is just half of expected if I put function generator waveform into the system. 
I suspect its the frequency bin calculation formula which I got wrong; currently using,         fft_peak_magnitude_index*sampling frequency / fft_size. 
My input is real and doing real fft. (output samples = N/2)
And also doing iir filtering and windowing before fft. 
Any suggestion would be a great help!

```
            // IIR filter calculation, n = 256 fft points       
        for (ctr=0; ctr<n; ctr++)
        {       
            // filter calculation
            y[ctr] = num_coef[0]*x[ctr];
            y[ctr] += (num_coef[1]*x[ctr-1]) - (den_coef[1]*y[ctr-1]);
            y[ctr] += (num_coef[2]*x[ctr-2]) - (den_coef[2]*y[ctr-2]);
            y1[ctr] = y[ctr] - 510; //eliminate dc offset

            // hamming window
            hamming[ctr] = (0.54-((0.46) * cos(2*M_PI*ctr/n)));
            window[ctr] = hamming[ctr]*y1[ctr];

            fft_input[ctr].r = window[ctr];
            fft_input[ctr].i = 0;
            fft_output[ctr].r = 0;
            fft_output[ctr].i = 0;
        }


        kiss_fftr_cfg fftConfig = kiss_fftr_alloc(n,0,NULL,NULL);
        kiss_fftr(fftConfig, (kiss_fft_scalar * )fft_input, fft_output);

        peak = 0;
        freq_bin = 0;       
        for (ctr=0; ctr<n1; ctr++)
            {   
                fft_mag[ctr] = 10*(sqrt((fft_output[ctr].r * fft_output[ctr].r) + (fft_output[ctr].i * fft_output[ctr].i)))/(0.5*n);

                if(fft_mag[ctr] > peak)
                {
                    peak = fft_mag[ctr];
                    freq_bin = ctr;
                }

            frequency = (freq_bin*(10989/n)); // 10989 is the sampling freq
                //************************************
                //Usart write
                char filtResult[10];
                //sprintf(filtResult, "%04d %04d %04d\n", (int)peak, (int)freq_bin, (int)frequency);
                sprintf(filtResult, "%04d  %04d  %04d\n", (int)x[ctr], (int)fft_mag[ctr], (int)frequency);
                char c;
                char *ptr = &filtResult[0];
                do
                {
                    c = *ptr;
                    ptr++;
                    usart_bw_write_char(&AVR32_USART2, (int)c);
                    // sendByte(c);

                } while (c != '\n');
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is likely to be how you declared `fft_input`.
Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30519032/2994596), you are allocating `fft_input` as an array of `kiss_fft_cpx`. The function `kiss_fftr` on the other hand expect an array of scalar. By casting the input array into a `kiss_fft_scalar` with:

```
kiss_fftr(fftConfig, (kiss_fft_scalar * )fft_input, fft_output);
```

KissFFT essentially sees an array of real-valued data which contains zeros every second sample (what you filled in as imaginary parts). This is effectively an upsampled version (although without interpolation) of your original signal, i.e. a signal with effectively twice the sampling rate (which is not accounted for in your `freq_bin` to `frequency` conversion). To fix this, I suggest you pack your data into a `kiss_fft_scalar` array:

```
kiss_fft_scalar fft_input[n];
...
for (ctr=0; ctr<n; ctr++)
{       
    ...
    fft_input[ctr] = window[ctr];
    ...
}
kiss_fftr_cfg fftConfig = kiss_fftr_alloc(n,0,NULL,NULL);
kiss_fftr(fftConfig, fft_input, fft_output);
```

Note also that while looking for the peak magnitude, you probably are only interested in the final largest peak, instead of the running maximum. As such, you could limit the loop to only computing the peak (using `freq_bin` instead of `ctr` as an array index in the following `sprintf` statements if needed):

```
for (ctr=0; ctr<n1; ctr++)
{   
  fft_mag[ctr] = 10*(sqrt((fft_output[ctr].r * fft_output[ctr].r) + (fft_output[ctr].i * fft_output[ctr].i)))/(0.5*n);

  if(fft_mag[ctr] > peak)
  {
    peak = fft_mag[ctr];
    freq_bin = ctr;
  }
} // close the loop here before computing "frequency"
```

Finally, when computing the frequency associated with the bin with the largest magnitude, you need the ensure the computation is done using floating point arithmetic. If as I suspect `n` is an integer, your formula would be performing the `10989/n` factor using integer arithmetic resulting in truncation. This can be simply remedied with:

```
frequency = (freq_bin*(10989.0/n)); // 10989 is the sampling freq
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer again. I've edited according to your suggestion which made a lot of sense. 
And function generator input gives me correct output now. However, now piezo output is doubled...so consistently two input conditions are out by factor of two..

Comment: Can't really comment on the piezo data acquisition since you haven't posted that part. However, the first things I'd check would be the sampling rate settings, and whether you are processing 8 or 16-bit samples.

Comment: i've just found out that piezo is just resonating at 840Hz...with cross checking with oscilloscope fft I have exact same pattern for fft magnitude. 
Thanks a lot!!